# How to make openoffice "comments" box bigger?

Tags: openoffice-writer, comments, openoffice

A friend made comments on an essay I wrote using openoffice's "Comments" feature. (Insert > Comment).

Those comments appear in little boxes on the right-hand side. But some times the comments get cut off and there is no scroll bar on that box. Other times there is a scroll bar.

What I want is to resize the little boxes on the right-hand side that contain those comments. I want them to auto-stretch to fit the comment, or I want to resize them manually so I don't need to scroll. Those little comment boxes don't have any resize handle bars when I put my mouse over it.

Is there something I can do to make those little comment boxes longer?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the cell the comment applies to, select "Show Comment", click in the comment and grab a corner of the comment box to enlarge it. When you're happy with the size, de-select "Show Comment"

Comment: What about for oowriter?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you meant calc. As far as I know there is no way to vary the size of the comment/note box in OOo Writer. I did a few searches of the OOo forum and extensions but found no mention of it there, that's not to say better search terms wouldn't find something.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a way to do this in LibreOffice Writer 6.0.7.3, but to make long comments easier to read you can decrease the font size of the comments and increase the zoom of the document. This will make more comment text fit on screen at the same apparent font size.

To decrease the comment font size, right click on a comment > format all comments > click on the font tab.

To increase the document zoom, click view > zoom.

Comment: This is a horrible solution and I hate that four years later it still appears to be the only thing that works.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same experience in Linux OOwriter. It is a fairly important defect.

A workaround is to export the document as a '.pdf'. In that format the text contains indicators to where a comment was inserted, and hovering over it shows the contents. With the '.pdf' on the left and the '.doc' (that was what I received) on the right it was possible to make progress. But it is clunky and far from satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

You edit the comment box space under show comments, not insert comment. Once you comments are shown click on mouse and use border points to resize box. I hope this helps.